# How do I parse "/Date(1459934700000)/" into a JavaScript Date object?

Tags: jquery, date

I'm trying to parse a date expressed as `"/Date(1459934700000)/"` via jQuery. I use this code :

```
new Date(parseInt(myDateString.substr(6)))
```

and get me this date :

```
Sun Apr 26 1970 02:58:20 GMT+0430 (Iran Standard Time)
```

But I want to get date such as `4/6/2016 12:45:00 PM`.

Comment: What is the value of `data[i].DepartureDateTime.substr(6)`?

Comment: putvande : "/Date(1459934700000)/"

Comment: There's nothing JSON related in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to create a custom function of your own like:

```js
var dt = "/Date(1459934700000)/"; // <---- actual date string 
dt = parseInt(dt.slice(6, -2), 10); // extract the date in ms and parsing it back to numbers


function dateConverter(d, sep){
  var d = new Date(d),   // <-------converting it back to a valid date here
      date = d.getDate(),
      month = d.getMonth()+1,
      year = d.getFullYear(),
      hrs = d.getHours(),
      min = d.getMinutes(),
      sec = d.getSeconds(),
      ampm = hrs >= 12 ? " PM" : " AM";
  
  return month+sep+date+sep+year+" "+hrs+":"+min+":"+sec+ampm;
  
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = dateConverter(dt, '/'); // <---passed the date in ms here
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Jai : In this line (var date = d.getDate(),) get me error that  getDate is not function.

Comment: make sure `d` is a date object.

Comment: @programmer138200 wait just updating  it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var testDate = 'Sun Apr 26 1970 02:58:20 GMT+0430 (Iran Standard Time)';
alert(moment(testDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```